# How can i convert a .htc file to javascript to support latest web browers

Tags: javascript, .net, web, asp-classic, dhtml

I try to convert a `.htc` file to a `.js` file, the htc file have public component tag is menu and html and CSS.  public component contains properties, methods, attached events. The `.htc` file calling from an `.aspx` page, but aspx page html dynamically generate from data base in form of xml with xslt.

Please let me know, the process of convert same functionality `.htc` to `.js`.

Comment: please let me know thank you